# Adding the submitted value to an existing cell value in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

in my google sheet, I have two tabs (Paid & Orders)

The user submits these inputs to Paid tab:

Bill # in column B and Paid Amount in column C

In Orders tab I have header Bills in column F and Existing Amount in column G

I need to compare the new submitted Bill # in Paid tab with Bills column in Orders tab and whenever we have a match, add the new submitted paid amount in Paid tab to the existing amount next to the matching bill number in bills column in Orders tab

In my google sheet script editor I have tried the below gs code:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
}

function doPost (e) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);

try {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Paid");
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

var bill = newRow[1];
var paidAmount = newRow[2];
var sh = doc.getSheetByName("Orders");
var bills = sh.getRange(2, 6, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

if (bills.flat().indexOf(bill) != -1) {
var existingAmount = sh.getRange(bills.flat().indexOf(bill)+2, 7).getValue();
var total = +existingAmount + +paidAmount
sh.getRange(bills.flat().indexOf(bill)+2, 7).setValue(total);
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Confirmation.html');
}
}

catch (e) {
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

finally { lock.releaseLock() }
}
```

Form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
<form action="ScriptURL" method="POST">
<select name="Bill #" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select ..</option>
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
<input type="number" placeholder="Paid" name="Paid Amount" required>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The data is submitted sucessfully but the **set value** is not working and also the script returns the following **The script completed but did not return anything.**

Any help, I would be so much grateful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modified script. But before you run the modified script, please confirm your settings of Spreadsheet for testing the modified script.

### Confirmation:

- In your script, it is required to set the 1st row of the sheets of `Paid` as follows.

  - The columns "A", "B" and "C" have `Timestamp`, `Bill` and `Paid Amount`, respectively.
  - And please set `1` and `2` for the numbers of `Bill` (the column "F") in the sheet `Orders`. By this, your modified HTML can be tested.
- About the settings of Web Apps, in your case, please test with `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`.

When the header row and the existing `Bill` value are not existing, the modified script cannot be tested. Please be careful this.

### Modification points:

- In your case, `createTemplateFromFile` cannot be used.
- `option` tag has no value.
- When you put `Bill` to the header, the name of `Bill #` cannot be used.
- When you want to use the values of `Bill` and `Paid Amount` as the number, `var bill = newRow[1];` and `var paidAmount = newRow[2];` are the string type. By this, `bills.flat().indexOf(bill) != -1` is always `false`. So the script in the if statement is not run.
- I think that in your case, `var total = +existingAmount + +paidAmount` can be modified to `var total = existingAmount +paidAmount`.
- In your script, when the value of `Bill` is not matched in the sheet `Orders`, an error returns.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side: `Form.html`

```
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec" method="POST">
    <select name="Bill" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select ..</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Paid" name="Paid Amount" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form.html');
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);
  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Paid");
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    var bill = Number(newRow[1]);
    var paidAmount = Number(newRow[2]);
    var sh = doc.getSheetByName("Orders");
    var bills = sh.getRange(2, 6, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
    if (bills.flat().indexOf(bill) != -1) {
      var existingAmount = sh.getRange(bills.flat().indexOf(bill)+2, 7).getValue();
      var total = existingAmount + paidAmount;
      sh.getRange(bills.flat().indexOf(bill)+2, 7).setValue(total);
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Confirmation.html');
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Value was not changed.");
  } catch (e) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- In your script, when `Confirmation.html` is not existing, an error occurs. Please be careful this.
- I think that your situation including the modified script might be a bit complicated. In my environment, I could confirm the modified script worked. But when you tested the modified script, if the script didn't work for your expected result, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the current script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

### References:

- [Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [Request parameters of Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike very much for detailed explanation. I followed your steps and it worked just fine. I think the main issue was that newRow[] returned a string and adding number before was a great modification to solve it

Comment: @i7 bih Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.